# How to use own objects in ColumnLayout in QML?

Tags: qt, layout, qml, alignment, anchor

I would like to produce a table where in every Row is a Text() and a ComboBox(). I want the comboboxes are aligned right and also the left side of the text labels something like that:

[image]

I have the main qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12



Window {
    id: wind
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Public Transport Searcher")
    property string oz: "Odjezdová zastávka"
    property string pz: "Příjezdová zastávka"
    property string co: "Čas odjezdu"




    Rectangle{
        id: rect
        x: wind.width/16
         implicitHeight: parent.height/3*2
         implicitWidth: wind.width/8*7
         anchors.right: parent.right
         anchors.left: parent.left
         anchors.margins: 20
        radius: 5


        color: "lightblue"

   ColumnLayout{
        id: cl
        spacing: 30
        width: parent.width
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.margins: 20
        anchors.fill: parent


    Row{
        id: r1
        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignTop
        //Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignTop
        Layout.margins: 15

        Text{
            id: r1t1
            text: "Vyhledávač jízdních řádů"
            font.pointSize: 16
            font.bold: true
        }
    }

     Line{

         id: r2
         tt2: oz
         Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft
         //anchors.top: r1.bottom
     }

     Line{

         id: r3
         tt2: pz
         Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft
     }

     Line{

         id: r4
         tt2: co
         Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft
     }


        }
    }


   }
```

And a separate Line.qml item:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12


Item {

     property string tt2: "v"

        Text{
            id: txt
            text: tt2
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            anchors.left: parent.left
        }
        ComboBox{
            id: cb
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            //anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.left: txt.right
        }

}
```

Now it runs but the all Rows are overwritting in the top left corner.
I know that I could use the GridLayout but I want to take advantage from the own objects for one row (in case I have much such rows) to avoid copy paste technic and initialise every object of the row separate.
Could you show me please how to do that in an elagant way?

Comment: I think what might be missing is there is no width/height for your Line items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `Line` items do not have any implicit size which the `ColumnLayout` can read from. That is, the `Line`'s base is just an `Item` whose default `implicitHeight` and `implicitWidth` are both 0 - so the `ColumnLayout` renders them improperly. You have several options.

One option is to add `implicitHeight`/`implicitWidth` (or `Layout.preferredWidth`/`Layout.preferredHeight`) to your `Line`'s `Item`:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

Item {
    implicitHeight: 30
    implicitWidth: parent.width
    property string tt2: "v"

    Text{
        id: txt
        text: tt2
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        anchors.left: parent.left
    }

    ComboBox{
        id: cb
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        //anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.left: txt.right
    }
}
```

A different way of accomplishing this would be to change the base of the `Line` to a `RowLayout` (and remove the interior anchors which would conflict):

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12

RowLayout {
    property string tt2: "v"

    Text {
        id: txt
        text: tt2
        Layout.preferredWidth: 200 // to align ComboBoxes, all text must have same width
        // Layout.fillWidth: true // a different option for aligning ComboBoxes
    }
        
    ComboBox {
        id: cb
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the second variant is that I am looking for, but one more problem, I dont know how to force the comboboxes to be algined above each other, now there are located next to the Texts which has different size und it looks terrible. The comboboxes could be aligned to the right margin too. When I add a width to the Text in Line.qml it does not help.

Comment: @FrantišekPrinz I have updated the second variant with some options. To align the comboboxes, the text width in each line must be uniform. By default, it is set to the visual width of the text, which varies depending on the string - instead you may hard-code all text to the same width to align the comboxes.

Comment: Thanks, I think, that's it!